# GWT RequestFactory

Tags: gwt, proxy, fetch, setter, requestfactory

Using GWT 2.5.1, i've got the following error :

```
com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.UnexpectedException: Could not locate
setter for property cptdossier in type org.nit.persistance.entites.Tllog
```

I have the feeling i misunderstood how to work with a primary key, but i don't how to fix it.

At this time, i'm clicking on a table and it is supposed to open a window filled with details.
This happens approximatively when it try to fetchRequest.to in the following

```
private void fetchAndEdit() {
    Request<TllogProxy> fetchRequest = requestFactory.createTllogRequest().find(tllog.getId(), tllog.getDatecre());
    fetchRequest.with(editorDriver.getPaths());
    fetchRequest.to(new Receiver<TllogProxy>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(TllogProxy tllog) {
        TllogEditorWorkflow.this.tllog = tllog;
        TllogRequest context = requestFactory.createTllogRequest();
        edit(context);
        context.persist(tllog);
      }
    }).fire();
  }
```

It tried to add dummy getters/setters in BaseTllog without success. 
May i have your guidance on this ?

This missing setter is refering to a field cptdossier which can be found in a primary key, both defined as follows :

```
public abstract class BaseTllog  implements Serializable {

    public BaseTllog () {
        initialize();
    }

    /**
     * Constructor for primary key
     */
    public BaseTllog (org.nit.persistance.entites.TllogPK id) {
        this.setId(id);
        initialize();
    }

    protected void initialize () {}



    private int hashCode = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    private org.nit.persistance.entites.TllogPK id;

    // fields
    private java.lang.Integer etafin;
    private java.util.Date datecre;
    private java.lang.String utilcre;
    private java.util.Date datemod;
    private java.lang.String utilmod;
    @Type(type="org.nit.usertype.HibernateXMLType")
    @Column(name="xmlbase_xml", columnDefinition="XDB.XMLTYPE")
    private String xmlbase;
    @Type(type="org.nit.usertype.HibernateXMLType")
    @Column(name="xmlcanvas_xml", columnDefinition="XDB.XMLTYPE")
    private String xmlcanvas;
    private java.lang.Long message;
    private java.lang.String fmb;
    private java.lang.String msgtxt;
    private java.lang.String dbmserrtext;


    public org.nit.persistance.entites.TllogPK getId () {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId (org.nit.persistance.entites.TllogPK id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.hashCode = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    + getters setters for others fields
}
```

TllogPK extends BaseTllogPK, which code is

```
public abstract class BaseTllogPK implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    protected int hashCode = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

    private java.lang.String metier;
    private java.lang.String sitegeo;
    private java.lang.String cptdossier;
    private java.lang.Integer numligne;

    public BaseTllogPK () {}

    public BaseTllogPK (
            java.lang.String metier,
            java.lang.String sitegeo,
            java.lang.String cptdossier,
            java.lang.Integer numligne
            ) {
        this.setMetier(metier);
        this.setSitegeo(sitegeo);
        this.setCptdossier(cptdossier);
        this.setNumligne(numligne);
    }

    + getters and setters
```

Tllog Proxy

```
@ProxyFor(value = Tllog.class, locator = TllogLocator.class)
public interface TllogProxy extends ValueProxy
{
    Integer getEtafin();
    void setEtafin(Integer etafin);
    TllogPKProxy getId();
    void setId(TllogPKProxy id);

    Date getDatecre();
        void setDatecre(Date datecre);
        String getUtilcre();
        void setUtilcre(java.lang.String utilcre);
        Date getDatemod();
        void setDatemod(java.util.Date datemod);
        String getUtilmod();
        void setUtilmod(java.lang.String utilmod);
        Long getMessage();
        void setMessage(java.lang.Long message);
        String getFmb();
        void setFmb(java.lang.String fmb);
        String getMsgtxt();
        void setMsgtxt(java.lang.String msgtxt);
        String getDbmserrtext();
        void setDbmserrtext(java.lang.String dbmserrtext);
}
```

proxy for TllogPK

```
@ProxyFor(value = TllogPK.class, locator = TllogLocator.class)
public interface TllogPKProxy extends ValueProxy
{
    String getCptdossier ();
    void setCptdossier (java.lang.String cptdossier);
    String getMetier ();
    void setMetier (java.lang.String metier);
    Integer getNumligne ();
    void setNumligne (java.lang.Integer numligne);
    String getSitegeo ();
    void setSitegeo (java.lang.String sitegeo);
}
```

Almost forgot Mapping file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping package="org.nit.persistance.entites">
    <class name="Tllog" table="TL_LOG" rowid="rowid"> 
        <meta attribute="sync-DAO">false</meta> 
        <composite-id name="id" class="TllogPK"> 
            <key-property name="metier"     column="TL_METIER"     type="string"/> 
            <key-property name="sitegeo"    column="TL_SITEGEO"    type="string"/> 
            <key-property name="cptdossier" column="TL_CPTDOSSIER" type="string"/> 
            <key-property name="numligne"   column="TL_NUMLIGNE"   type="integer"/> 
        </composite-id> 
        <property name="etafin"      column="TL_ETAFIN"       type="integer"/> 
        <property name="datecre"     column="TL_DATECRE"      type="timestamp"/> 
        <property name="utilcre"     column="TL_UTILCRE"      type="string" length="20" update="false"/> 
        <property name="datemod"     column="TL_DATEMOD"      type="timestamp"/>
        <property name="utilmod"     column="TL_UTILMOD"      type="string" length="20" insert="false"/>
        <property name="xmlbase"     column="XML_BASE"   type="org.nit.data.HibernateXMLType"/> 
        <property name="xmlcanvas"   column="XML_CANVAS"    type="org.nit.data.HibernateXMLType"/> 
        <property name="message"     column="TL_MESSAGE"       type="long"/> 
        <property name="fmb"         column="TL_FMB" type="string"/> 
        <property name="msgtxt"      column="MSGTXT" type="string"/>
        <property name="dbmserrtext" column="DBMSERRTEXT" type="string"/>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

TllogLocator

```
import java.util.Date;
import com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.shared.Locator;
import org.nit.persistance.entites.Tllog;
import org.nit.persistance.entites.TllogPK;

public class TllogLocator extends Locator<Tllog, TllogPK>
{
    @Override
    public Tllog create (Class<? extends Tllog> clazz)
    {
        return new Tllog();
    }

    @Override
    public Tllog find (Class<? extends Tllog> clazz, TllogPK id)
    {
        return CEMTllog.fetch(id, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Tllog> getDomainType ()
    {
        return Tllog.class;
    }

    @Override
    public TllogPK getId (Tllog tllog)
    {
        return tllog.getId();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<TllogPK> getIdType ()
    {
        return TllogPK.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getVersion (Tllog tllog)
    {
        return new Date(); 
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,

Pierre

Comment: Looks OK. This error message is usually pretty reliable except for... do you have any other classes (with proxies) that extend the base class containing "cptdossier"? If you don't provide it GWT gives this really unhelpful message. e.g. ProxyX and ProxyY extends ProxyB.  ProxyB declares some method that is not implemented in PojoY. Sadly in this case the error message doesn't mention PojoY.

Comment: Thanks for replying so fast salk31.
After investigating, TllogPK is the only entity extending BaseTllogPK
Only locator class is the same.

Don't know if this is relevant, but i've juste added locator code to the thread.

Tks

public class TllogLocator extends Locator<Tllog, TllogPK>

Comment: It is more if something extends TllogPKProxy... For good of bad RequestFactory lets the proxy and pojo class hierarchy be different.

Comment: It is complaining about Tllog though so more likely a problem with the TllogProxy class hierarchy. Sorry if I've added confusion.

Comment: Don't be because you pointed me in the right direction.
I did change TllogPK to be 
@ProxyFor(value = TllogPK.class, locator = TllogPKLocator.class)

Obviously, i created a TllogPKLocator and believe it or not ... it's working.

Comment: Thanks a million salk31